# What's the best lubricant for a refrigerator water dispenser switch?

Tags: refrigerator, switch, lubrication

The water dispenser on my refrigerator sticks when you press it in. Sometimes it pops right out, and sometimes it stays in for 10-15 seconds. I've taken it apart a couple of times, cleaned it out, and tried spraying lithium grease and Liquid Wrench "Dry Lubricant" in there. Both work for a few weeks, then it starts sticking again, and gets worse over time.

The switch is a little plastic wedge that slides inside a plastic opening. Any tips?

Comment: are you talking about the electrical switch?

Comment: It's the switch that opens up the water valve when you press your cup against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's entirely a mechanical valve, then use food-safe silicone grease. If it still sticks, you can just replace it.

If it's an electrical switch that opens a solenoid on a water valve, then you should just replace the switch.

I've had really good luck getting replacement parts and advice from http://www.repairclinic.com

Comment: Thanks, I used some silicone grease and it's working great. I'll update the thread in a few months when I see how it holds up.

Answer (score 1):

You could try silicone grease. It's usually used to lubricate O-rings. It's food safe. You can  buy a small container at the home store for a few dollars.